# How can I create a "proxy" openGL texture in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am porting an app to Qt and have troubles with the integration of the Syphon framework (http://syphon.v002.info/) which is used for video streams sharing between applications via the GPU (Mac OS X only).

Two C++ implementations for Syphon are available, one for Cinder (github/astellato/Cinder-Syphon) and one for openFrameworks (github/astellato/ofxSyphon). I started from the Cinder implementation (both are quite similar) and tried to port it to Qt but I can't find a way to create a `QOpenGlTexture` using an already created texture.

Here is the code from Cinder-Syphon that I'm trying to get to work (file `syphonClient.mm`) :

```
void syphonClient::bind()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if(bSetup)
    {
        [(SyphonNameboundClient*)mClient lockClient];
        SyphonClient *client = [(SyphonNameboundClient*)mClient client];

        latestImage = [client newFrameImageForContext:CGLGetCurrentContext()];
        NSSize texSize = [(SyphonImage*)latestImage textureSize];
        GLuint m_id = [(SyphonImage*)latestImage textureName];

        mTex = ci::gl::Texture::create(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, m_id,
                               texSize.width, texSize.height, true);
        mTex->setFlipped();

        mTex->bind();
    } 
    else
        std::cout<<"syphonClient is not setup, or is not properly connected to server.  Cannot bind.\n";

    [pool drain];
}
```

In the Qt version I'm writing, `mTex` is of type `QOpenGlTexture` but I couldn't find an equivalent of `mTex = ci::gl::Texture::create(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, m_id, texSize.width, texSize.height, true);`, that is, creating a `QOpenGLTexture` using an existing texture ID without having to allocate storage again.

Did I miss something in the Qt OpenGL API or is it just not possible ? If not I guess I will have to use direct OpenGL calls or pulling in the whole Cinder OpenGL API ?

Comment: Why not use the OpenGL functions directly? I seriously don't see any sane reason to use (or actually implement) framework specific wrappers for standard OpenGL objects.

Comment: That makes sense... I thought it would be easier to interact with Qt objects later but it doesn't seem to make a real difference.